# Where did RU/m go?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

This used to be a feature of CosmosDb to provision Request Units Per Minute (as well as Request Units Per Second) however the option appears to have disappeared from the portal and all online documentation has been removed?

Thanks, Oliver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RU/m is dead

**Just received a response from Microsoft**

> We received a ton of feedback from our customers who participated in the Preview program; starting 8/25/2017, we have officially closed the Preview program for RU/M. Based on all customer feedback, we believe that we have a good understanding of how we can dramatically improve the capability by making it easier to use and by making it useful across all workloads (instead of a just few).

Answer (score 1):

It was a preview feature that is <del>not</del> now retired.