# CosmosDB - what does FeedOptions.DisableRUPerMinuteUsage actually do?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When making a CosmosDB query using the .NET SDK, one can specify options for that query, in the form of a `FeedOptions` object.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.disableruperminuteusage?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Documents_Client_FeedOptions_DisableRUPerMinuteUsage) for property `FeedOptions.DisableRUPerMinuteUsage` is pretty slim:

> DisableRUPerMinuteUsage is used to enable/disable Request Units(RUs)/minute capacity to serve the query if regular provisioned RUs/second is exhausted.

Are there two provisioning options available? RU/s and RU/min ?
I don't see anything like that in the 'Scale' settings page in Azure Portal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did RU/m go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47281086/where-did-ru-m-go)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got an answer from **[`COSMOSDB team member`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641598/matias-quaranta)** ,

> That option was targeting a preview feature called "RU per minute".
> The idea behind this feature was to offer a mechanism for customers to
> insure against unexpected spikes in their workload. We have officially
> closed the Preview program for RU/M.

Comment: [Citation needed] :)